# MySQL slow performance when selecting from many rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have more than 4000 rows of data in my table. I have noticed that it gets extremely slow and it even freezes when I try to fetch all rows from mysql workbench.

After some trial and errors, I noticed it will only freeze/low performance if i select more than 1544 rows.

```
SELECT *  FROM users LIMIT 1544;
```

**EDIT**

Here are some data after running `DESC Users`

```
Field,         Type,            Null,  Key,  Default, Extra
'id',          'int(10) unsigned','NO','PRI',NULL, 'auto_increment'
'email',       'varchar(255)',  'NO',  '',   NULL, ''
'password',    'varchar(255)',  'YES', '',   NULL, ''
'first_name',  'varchar(255)',  'YES', '',   NULL, ''
'last_name',   'varchar(255)',  'YES', '',   NULL, ''
'gender',      'varchar(15)',   'YES', '',   NULL, ''
'picture',     'varchar(255)',  'YES', '',   NULL, ''
'contact_number','varchar(255)','YES', '',   NULL, ''
'country',     'varchar(255)',  'YES', '',   NULL, ''
'state',       'varchar(255)',  'YES', '',   NULL, ''
'city',        'varchar(255)',  'YES', '',   NULL, ''
'dob',         'date',          'YES', '',   NULL, ''
'type',        'int(11)',       'NO',  '',   '1', ''
'verified',    'int(11)',       'NO',  '',   '0', ''
'is_first_login','int(11)',     'NO',  '',   '1', ''
'status',      'int(11)',       'NO',  '',   '1', ''
'remember_token','text',        'YES', '',   NULL, ''
'created_at',  'timestamp',     'NO',  '',   '0000-00-00 00:00:00', ''
'updated_at',  'timestamp',     'NO',  '',   '0000-00-00 00:00:00', ''
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: First thing limit without order by is meaningless, you may do an order by with primary key before the limit.

Comment: Can you show us your structure? Its a bit difficult to find problems without that.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty well it is ordering by id... do i have to explicitly order it? will that solve my problem?

Comment: Can you run `explain SELECT * FROM foo.bar LIMIT 1544;` and show the output?

Comment: @TommyLee thats a wrong notion,mysql stores data which are unordered and unless explicitly order by is used there is no guarantee of getting ordered data. And Yes user `order by id`  and since id is primary key it will use index to sort the data which will be faster.

Comment: Try to add some indexes on table.

Comment: @tigger `'1', 'SIMPLE', 'users', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '4634', NULL` this is what i got

Comment: OK, now run `desc users` and update the question with the data so we can all make something more than a guess as to what is going on.

Comment: It looks like you are selecting a lot of data that is not needed. Besides that, only the `id` has any kind of indexing (Key). That means every fast query is going to have to be against the `id` column. For example `select id from user where email = 'test@example.com'` will be a slow query (because of the lack of an index on that column), but `select email from users where id = '1003'` will be faster.

Comment: OK, your table design is pretty rough. For example, both `is_first_login` and `remember_token` could be a `tinyint(1) unsigned` instead just for a start. I'm not sure of any "states" that require `varchar(255)` either (maybe in Wales?).

Comment: @Tigger so it means that, these slow performance is to be expected as data grows? what i need to do now is to optimize my table so that it does not take more spaces than needed?

Comment: Tommy, can you add a bit more info about your environment? What WB version do you use (latest?), which OS? Do you work locally or over a network? Did you try to run the query in the MySQL CLI? Is it quicker there?

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions :**

1. Instead of * use field names.
2. If you need all data at once than you can use conditions and can use limits.
3. If you need some data then you can use pagination, load other data then user scroll down.
4. you can create view for it and call the view.

Comment: so this slow performance is normal? and nobody selects so many rows of data at once?

Answer (score 0):

Please make index for column which is to be used for select purpose.Also make table structure datatype length will be decrease as per your need

Suppose as an Ex. contact_number varchar(255) is not required, varchar(10) its more enough for.

Its a best way to optimize your table and fast retrial of data from table

Answer (score 0):

for large databases Mysql INDEX can be helpful in speed problems, An index can be created in a table to find data more quickly and efficiently. so must create index , you can learn more about MYsql index here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp